# Sort Multidimensiional associative array by multiplying two key values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array as shown below:

```
$myarray = array(
   array('itemid' => '1','height'=>'5','length' => '5'),//area=25(height*length)
   array('itemid' => '2','height'=>'2','length' => '5'),//area=10(height*length)
   array('itemid' => '3','height'=>'5','length' => '3'),//area=15(height*length) 
  );
```

I would like to sort it in the ascending order by calculating the area by multiplying height and length (string values) of each array item as shown below

```
$sortedarray = array(
   array('itemid' => '2','height'=>'2','length' => '5'),//area=10(height*length)
   array('itemid' => '3','height'=>'5','length' => '3'),//area=15(height*length)
   array('itemid' => '1','height'=>'5','length' => '5'),//area=25(height*length)
);
```

I know that php has `array_multisort` function but I need to sort by calculating the area.

Comment: Oof I have used `usort` for this kinds of stuff. Lemme see if I can still find out how that worked. **edit** Ninja'd by Eddie it seems haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `usort`.

Usort callback function expects, -1 (negative number) if `$a` is first. 1 (positive number) if `$b` is should go first and `0` if no change on order.

Example:
The area of `$a` is 25 and `$b` is 10. `25-10 = 15` which is a positive number. So `usort` will order `$b` ahead of `$a`

```
$myarray = array(
    array('itemid' => '1','height'=>'5','length' => '5'),//area=25
    array('itemid' => '2','height'=>'2','length' => '5'),//area=10
    array('itemid' => '3','height'=>'5','length' => '3'),//area=15 
);

usort( $myarray, function($a, $b){
    return ( $a['height'] * $a['length'] )  - ( $b['height'] * $b['length'] );
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $myarray );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 1
            [height] => 5
            [length] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 3
            [height] => 5
            [length] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 2
            [height] => 2
            [length] => 5
        )

)
```

Doc: [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: Can you explain to me what you did in that return statement?(why subtraction)

Comment: I got it if the next value is greater than the previous one it should return in negative and vice versa

Comment: @NawazGhori I added an explanation. Please let me know if you have Qs. :)